# Visual Studio 2015 WPF Project ToolBox Drag and Drop takes too long

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, I

1- create or open a wpf project

2- open a xaml file

3- from toolbox drag anything (like button) to the designer

4- it takes about 15 seconds to drop it

no problem after that.

Anyone can help me fix that delay?

Comment: update GPU drivers or disable HW acceleration in VS options

Comment: thanks, but doesn't fix it

Comment: what? driver update? software rendering?